# How to handle JWT authentication with RxDB?

Tags: authentication, couchdb, pouchdb, jwt, rxdb

I have a local RxDB database and I want to connect it with CouchDB. Everything seems to works fine except for authentication. I have no idea how to add it differently then inserting credentials in database url:

```
database.tasks.sync({
        remote: `http://${username}:${pass}@127.0.0.1:5984/tododb`,
      });
```

I would like to use JWT auth but can't find how to add a token to sync request. I found only some solutions for PouchDB (pouchdb-authentication plugin) but can't get it working with RxDB.

Comment: A fairly broad question.  I've always used header auth (i.e. basic) over HTTPS, which is secure enough for my cases. Have you read over [CouchDB's Authentication docs](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/server/authn.html#authentication)?

Comment: Yes, I read it but I mean - don't know how to add anything to RxDB request header. For base auth (my example from question) it's converted and added automatically but how can I add to this header cookie or JWT token?

Answer (score 5):

RxDB is tightly coupled with PouchDB and uses its sync implementation under the hood. To my understanding, the only way to add custom headers to a remote PouchDB instance (which is what is created for you when you pass a url as the `remote` argument in `sync`), is to [intercept the HTTP request](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#create_database):

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://example.com/dbname', {
  fetch: function (url, opts) {
    opts.headers.set('X-Some-Special-Header', 'foo');
    return PouchDB.fetch(url, opts);
  }
});
```

[PouchDB replication documentation](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication) (sync) also states that:

> The remoteDB can either be a string or a PouchDB object. If you have a fetch override on a remote database, you will want to use PouchDB objects instead of strings, so that the options are used.

Luckily, RxDB's `Rx.Collection.sync` does not only accept an server url as the `remote` argument, but also another RxCollection or a PouchDB-instance.

RxDB even reexport the internally used PouchDB module, so you do not have to install PouchDB as a direct dependency.

```
import { ..., PouchDB } from 'rxdb';

// ...


const remotePouch = new PouchDB('http://27.0.0.1:5984/tododb', {
  fetch: function (url, opts) {
    opts.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${getYourJWTToken()}`)
    return PouchDB.fetch(url, opts);
  }
})

database.tasks.sync({
  remote: remotePouch,
});
```